# I wanna create CSV reader that analyzes credit card information

Tags: java

Im making a CSV Reader but im getting a NullPointerException
It says:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Scanner.nextLine()" because "this.s" is null
at csvReader.scanner(csvReader.java:34)
at csvReader.(csvReader.java:23)

Heres my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
/**
 * Write a description of class csvReader here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class csvReader
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int x;
    private Scanner s;
    private static StringTokenizer tokenizer;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class csvReader
     */
    public csvReader()
    {
        scanner();
    }

    private static String[] getTokens (String input) {
        String[] tokens = new String[5];
        // Create empty String in each of 5 locations so
        // I can add to them
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
            tokens[i] = "";
        }
    
        int index = 0; // location in array
        int pointer = 0; // location in the String
        boolean inQuotes = false; // to keep track of whether the pointer
        // within quotes - ignore commas
        while (true){
            if (pointer == input.length()){
                break;
            }
            if (input.charAt(pointer) == '\"'){
                if (inQuotes){      
                    inQuotes = false;
                } else {
                    inQuotes = true;
                }
            }
            else if (input.charAt(pointer) == ','){
                if (inQuotes){ // while between quotes
                    // commas get added at end of current token
                    tokens[index] += input.charAt(pointer);
                } else {
                    // when not in quotes, comma means move on
                    // to next token
                    index++;
                }
            }
            else {
                // anything other than " or , will get added to the end
                // of my current token.
                tokens[index] += input.charAt(pointer);
            }
            pointer++;
        }
    
        return tokens;
    }
    
    public void scanner()
    {
        boolean moreLines = true;
        int numTransactions = 0;
        while (moreLines)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println(s.nextLine());
                numTransactions++;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e)
            {
                moreLines = false;
                System.out.println("There are " + numTransactions + "transactions");
            }
        }
        
        try {
            s = new Scanner (new File ("visadata.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        } 
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

I wanted the scanner to tell me how many total transactions there are, the number of debit and credit transactions, and the total of all debit transactions. Im stuck on finding the total number of transactions right now but im getting a NullPointerException

Comment: Don't call scanner method from the constructor

Comment: You attempt to use your `Scanner` before initializing it, so it's null. You would be better off posting an example of your data too. Method [names](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions) should be verbal, not based on nouns. Class names begin uppercase. There's rarely any need to scan a file to find out how many lines it has. Use a collection and add them all. I suspect in your case, you might be better off using a proper CSV API

Answer (score 0):

In your `scanner()` function, you are attempting to use the class property `s` to read lines. The loop will always start because `moreLines` is set to `true` immediately after. You attempt/`try` to read the lines from the scanner and `catch` if there isn't a line (which is good). But what happens if `s` hasn't been initialized yet?

When you start your program, `s` is declared to be a Scanner but it hasn't been built -> **it is null**.

Attempting to run a method on a null object throws a `NullPointerException`, which is your problem. You are only initializing `s` after the loop, so the `NullPointerException` will be thrown at least once.

```
   boolean moreLines = true;
    int numTransactions = 0;
    while (moreLines)
    {
        try
        {
            // s does not exist yet
            System.out.println(s.nextLine()); // s.nextLine() throws NullPointerException
            numTransactions++;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            moreLines = false;
            System.out.println("There are " + numTransactions + "transactions");
        }
    }
    
    try {
        // Only initialized here
        s = new Scanner (new File ("visadata.txt"));
    }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }
```

You need to either initialize the Scanner earlier in the program (maybe in the class constructor) or, if you want to maintain the same logic, also `catch` `NullPointerException`s to indicate that there are no lines to read.

```
    try 
    {
      System.out.println(s.nextLine());
      numTransactions++;
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
      moreLines = false;
      System.out.println("There are " + numTransactions + "transactions");
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e)
    {
      moreLines = false;
      System.out.println("There are " + numTransactions + "transactions");
    }
```

This type of `Exception` is built-in so you should not need to `import` it.